# Batch command returns invalid parameter error for image size compression

Tags: command-line, windows-8.1, batch-file, cmd.exe, compression

I am trying to run the below command to compress file size of images on Windows System and it return error message saying **Invalid Parameter 70**

```
for %f IN (*.png) DO convert -quality 70 "%f" "%f"
```

I tried googling for a solution but couldn't find anything.

Is the syntax of the command wrong?

OR

Does this not work at all?

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### It returns an error message saying `Invalid Parameter 70`

```
for %f IN (*.png) DO convert -quality 70 "%f" "%f"
```

I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to do here, but `convert` is not the program you think it is (it has nothing to do with image conversion - hence the error).

> Is the syntax of the command wrong?

Yes. `convert` has the following syntax:

```
f:\test>convert /?
Converts a FAT volume to NTFS.

CONVERT volume /FS:NTFS [/V] [/CvtArea:filename] [/NoSecurity] [/X]


  volume      Specifies the drive letter (followed by a colon),
              mount point, or volume name.
  /FS:NTFS    Specifies that the volume will be converted to NTFS.
  /V          Specifies that Convert will be run in verbose mode.
  /CvtArea:filename
              Specifies a contiguous file in the root directory
              that will be the place holder for NTFS system files.
  /NoSecurity Specifies that the security settings on the converted
              files and directories allow access by all users.
  /X          Forces the volume to dismount first if necessary.
              All open handles to the volume will not be valid.
```

I suspect that `convert -quality 70 "%f" "%f"` are the arguments to some other program and you need to adjust your `for` command as appropriate to call the correct program.

Comment: I guess you are right. If I do get find the link where I got this command from I'll make sure to leave a comment that this in not a built-in DOS command it's ImageMagick command and we need to install ImageMagick for this to work! I'll mark this answer as accepted! Thanks